# Using apiclient.discovery.build for reseller api

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-reseller-api

I'm trying to create a `service` for the `reseller api` in python-2.7 that includes `oauth 2.0`. Oauth 2.0 is working correctly because, I have verified that I can get an `access token`. I have this error message because I can't find the right documentation for reseller service. Despite reading the code inside `apiclient.discovery.build`, can anybody help me identify the problem (The question is on the last part of this message).

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\reseller-asteriainteractive\oauth2client\appengine.py", line 777, in setup_oauth
    resp = method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\reseller-asteriainteractive\main.py", line 74, in post
    customer_document = customers.insert().execute(decorator.http())
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\reseller-asteriainteractive\apiclient\discovery.py", line 583, in method
    raise TypeError('Missing required parameter "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Missing required parameter "body"
```

Here is my code:

```
class CustomerCreateHandler(BaseHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_aware
  def post(self):
    admin_user = users.is_current_user_admin()
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
      if decorator.has_credentials():
        customers = reseller_service.customers()
        customer_document = customers.insert().execute(decorator.http())
        self.redirect('/customer/create/')
```

How should the reseller_service be constructed? Where should I put the "body" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome!

I finally found this in Google API client library: 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/reseller/v1sandbox/python/latest/reseller_v1sandbox.customers.html